# How do I pass a class as a parameter in Swift?

Tags: swift

I want to write a function with the below signature:

```
func viewHasSuperviewOfClass(view: UIView, superclass: AnyObject.Type) -> Bool {
    return view.superview is superclass
}
```

But it won't compile. What am I doing wrong? How do I pass the superclass and treat it as a parameter?

Comment: try using view.superview.isKindOfClass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the `superclass` as `AnyClass` and use `isKind(of:)` to test it:

```
func viewHasSuperviewOfClass(view: UIView, superclass: AnyClass) -> Bool {
    return view.superview?.isKind(of: superclass) ?? false
}
```

Since `view.superview` is an optional you need to unwrap it.  Using *optional chaining* will return `nil` if there is no superview, so use the *nil coalescing operator* `??` to return `false` if there is no `superview`.

---

**Example:**

```
let button = UIButton()
let label = UILabel()
label.addSubview(button)

viewHasSuperviewOfClass(view: button, superclass: UILabel.self)  // true
viewHasSuperviewOfClass(view: label, superclass: UIButton.self)  // false
```

---

It will read a little better if you make the function signature this:

```
func view(_ view: UIView, hasSuperviewOfClass superclass: AnyClass) -> Bool {
    return view.superview?.isKind(of: superclass) ?? false
}

// example call
view(button, hasSuperviewOfClass: UILabel.self)
```